# access to particles's property in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, particles

so I've created a particle system with particle designer and added to my project :

```c
emitter =[CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"bonparticle9.plist"];
emitter.position=ccp(size.width/2,size.height/2);
[self addChild:emitter z:10];
```

I would like to know if with code I can access to the property of my particle. For example during the game modify the speed of my particle . thank you :) sorry for my english I'm french :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `emitter` is a `CCParticleSystemQuad` object, that means you have access to all the properties of [`CCParticleSystem`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_particle_system.html) class. Things like `duration`, `life`, `speed`, `speedVar`... are all accessable.